Why returning Self that rpresent &str in rust compiles successfully
I the following code
trait Random {
    fn generate() -> Self;
}

impl Random for &str {
    // This compiles successfully
    fn generate() -> Self {
        "foo"
    }

    // This does not compile
    //fn generate() -> &str {
    //    "foo"
    //}
}

fn random<T>() -> T
where
    T: Random,
{
    T::generate()
}

fn main() {
    let v: &str = random();
    println!("you get {}", v);
}

I don't understand why when I return Selfit doesn't complain about expected named lifetime parameter  even that Self here represent &str
from what I understand is because Self represents &str so I have to specify its lifetime by adding 'static for example, but the code compiles successfully without the need of doing this

This is not specific to the trait method. You can also write:
fn generate <'a>() -> &'a str { "foo" }

The type of generate is a contract - given ANY lifetime 'a, it promise to give you an str reference which lives at least as long as as 'a. A literal satisfies that because a literals lifetime is 'static, and the 'static is at least as long as any other lifetime.
Note also that a reference type implementing a trait method implicitly binds a lifetime parameter, so that your trait implementation is exactly the same as
impl <'a> Random for &'a str { ... }

The signature of
fn generate() -> Self 

will not give you the "expected named lifetime parameter" error because here Self does have a lifetime, namely, the lifetime of the reference type bound in ... for &'a str.

AFAICS the answer is slightly missing the point of the question: The question is not about the relation of 'static to any other lifetime (that is, why this example works), but why the nominal type in the impl trait block does not have to explicitly name the implicit lifetime parameter in &str at all; the question is about syntax
